# Can't Find GoogleMaps In googlemaps Package

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps

I tried this import statement and it did not work:

```
from googlemaps import GoogleMaps
```

This is the code I want to run:

```
address = "207 N. Defiance St, Archbald, OH"
print(GoogleMaps().address_to_latlng(address))
```

I installed the package using the code below:

```
conda install -c conda-forge googlemaps
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 from googlemaps.client import Client

 [...]

 address = "207 N. Defiance St, Archbald, OH"
 print(Client().address_to_latlng(address))
```